# ObjXMLDoc.async = False

Tags: asynchronous, vbscript

im writing a vbscript.

' Create the XML DOM object

```
Set ObjXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
ObjXMLDoc.async = False
```

what does " ObjXMLDoc.async = False " mean?

or i can just ignore the meaning and place this sentence there, treat it like a ...tradition?

Answer (score 0):

It means that if you do a request with that object the script waits until the result is fully returned, otherwise it moves on and you have to work with a callback routine to do something with the results or put up a loop in which you check with a timeinterval if the result is complete.
Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx before you carry on.